# Libgdx Set random position

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a way to generate random positions for each image found in this array

```
int x = 0;
x+=100;

    for (int p=0;p<name.size;p++){
        stage.addActor(name.get(r));
        System.out.println("Set card "+ r +" At position "+ x );
        name.get(r).setPosition(x,0);
        //name.random().setPosition(x,0);
}
```

I know this code would display all the images at one position but is there a way to display every image at different positions along the x-axis

*The members of the array is an image type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the following line into your for loop.

`x = (int)(Math.random()*101);`

If the x-axis stretches beyond 100, just change the 101 to whatever number it stretches to +1.

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx have `MathUtils` for help you with numbers and Math stuff.

You can use `x = MathUtils.random(0, 100);` in your for loop

`random(int start, int end)` return a int between start (inclusive) and end (inclusive)